# Lattice Modifier not listing available objects

Tags: modifiers, lattice

I am just trying to use a lattice deformer but somehow I can't see any available objects in the objects property.

[image]

Using Blender 2.79b under macOS High Sierra.

Comment: The [Lattice Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html) expects a [Lattice object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/lattice.html) as a target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a lattice object to the scene (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>> *Lattice*). Then, after selecting the object you want to add the lattice to *then* the lattice (the order matters), you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>> *Lattice deform*.